# Error using 'this' in a cs page trying to access control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a page called test.aspx with test.cs.
However, i want to access my control called mbResult
Which is my custom messagebox control, from a sepearate CS page.
I know many people have asked this question and i have found that this is a method to access my controls.

```
MessageBoxControl mbox1 = this.FindControl("mbResult") as MessageBoxControl;
```

But I keep getting this error
**Error 5   Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer**

Any ideas on how to access this control all i am trying to do is make it visible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the code into a non-shared method. You need to be operating in an instance of the page.

**Update for clarification in comments**

Unfortunately, your application is going to need some restructuring.

If the messageboxcontrol is shown in a new window, then you will need to pass the value from your source page to the new window in the query string.

However, if you want the messagebox control to be displayed on the source page, then you will need to convert it from a page to a UserControl, add a reference to the user control to your source page, and then add an instance of the usercontrol directly to the source page.

Comment: hmm im not quite sure how to implement this. would i create the method on the test.aspx page or in my new cs page.

Comment: You would add the method on test.cs. However, now that I think about it, you won't be able to do this since you won't have the two pages instantiated in the same request. Can you indicate what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to send the value from one page to the other page?

Comment: hmmm i want to be able to change the text of my messageboxcontrol from my cs page the reason is, it is going to be handling a portion of code, and if there is an exception i want the messagebox to be shown along with the error

Comment: Updated the answer with additional clarification based on the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Statics don't have instance-based contexts, so using `this` is not applicable.  You'll need a reference to the control for which you want to use .FindControl (possibly by passing it as a parameter).